# Unity 3d object hold problem how can i fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I fix this event if the character moves without the mouse to move the object is not followed by the player stays where it is. The mouse should move for the object to follow, how do I solve this?
Here's my script how works https://youtu.be/f5P5epEA3-w

My code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class ObjectHoldRay : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform player;
        public Transform Kamera;
        private Camera playerCam;
        public float throwForce = 10;
        bool hasPlayer = false;
        bool beingCarried = false;
        public AudioClip[] soundToPlay;
        public int dmg;
        private bool touched = false;
        public float mesafe;
        private Ray playerAim;

        void Start()
        {
        }

        void Update()
        {
            playerCam = Camera.main;
            Ray playerAim = playerCam.GetComponent<Camera>().ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(playerAim, out hit, mesafe))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "tasinabilir")
                {
                    hasPlayer = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    hasPlayer = false;
                }
                if (hasPlayer && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
                    transform.parent = Kamera;
                    beingCarried = true;
                }
                if (beingCarried)
                {
                    if (touched)
                    {
                        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                        transform.parent = null;
                        beingCarried = false;
                        touched = false;
                    }
                    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f) // forward
                    {
                        Debug.Log("İLeri");
                    }
                    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f) // geri
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Geri");
                    }
                    //if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                    //{
                    //  GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                    //transform.parent = null;
                    //beingCarried = false;
                    //GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(playerCam.forward * throwForce);
                    //}
                    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
                    {
                        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
                        transform.parent = null;
                        beingCarried = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void OnTriggerEnter()
        {
            if (beingCarried)
            {
                touched = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make your movable object as child of player instead of camera after picking?

```
transform.parent = player;
```

Comment: After i pick up object already its being child of player but this code not worked transform.parent = player;